# код Angularjs в jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs

что не так тут?

https://jsfiddle.net/f03j76mq/40/

```
код - по ссылке
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: про F12 то я и забыл..., спасибо

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/bdmqxr5y/ почему тут нет ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что ангуляр загружен 2 раза.
Слева в Resources и на окне яваскрипта.
Если одну убрать и перенести яваскрипт в `<head>` - всё работает.

Comment: спасибо, теперь гуд